# why is the directory not found from my dragged and downloaded file?

Tags: directory

I can drag and dropped a downloaded file into Ubuntu but it said it can't find the directory

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must use the `/` symbol to separate directories.

You've used `\` which resulted in a syntax error.